# Longest path and coloring

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification

Let $G$ be a graph such that its longest path has length $l$. I want to prove that
$$ \chi(G) \leq l + 1. $$
A Theorem in my notes explicitly states that if $D$ is an orientation of a graph $G$ which has longest path length $l$, then
$$ \chi(G) \leq l + 1 .$$
Isn't the claim then just following from this theorem by just choosing an orientation that respects this path i.e. to every edge of this path one assigns the same direction?

Comment: The theorem we need does seem to be a direct corollary to the one in the notes.

Comment: I think you are referring to the [Gallai-Hasse-Roy-Vitaver theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallai%E2%80%93Hasse%E2%80%93Roy%E2%80%93Vitaver_theorem). See that Wiki article for a good proof, and for a discussion of how orientations come into play. Something similar was asked on this site: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/958333/upper-bound-on-chromatic-number-characterization-with-longest-directed-path/ (my answer is partially wrong).